# Add column to middle of tab-delimited file (sed/awk/whatever)

Tags: sed, awk

I'm trying to add a column (with the content '0') to the middle of a pre-existing tab-delimited text file. I imagine `sed` or `awk` will do what I want. I've seen various solutions online that do approximately this but they're not explained simply enough for me to modify!

I currently have this content:

```
Affx-11749850   1       555296  CC
```

I need this content

```
Affx-11749850   1   0   555296  CC
```

Using the command `awk '{$3=0}1'` filename messes up my formatting AND replaces column 3 with a 0, rather than adding a third column with a 0.

Any help (with explanation!) so I can solve this problem, and future similar problems, much appreciated.

Comment: A related question - the file has 280 columns, and I'd like to switch around columns one and two, cut I'm not sure how to achieve that without typing out some kind of massive print statement $277, $278,$279...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the implicit `{ print }` rule and appending the `0` to the second column:

```
awk '$2 = $2 FS "0"' file
```

Or with `sed`, assuming single space delimiters:

```
sed 's/ / 0 /2' file
```

Or `perl`:

```
perl -lane '$, = " "; $F[1] .= " 0"; print @F'
```

Comment: A very similar option for AWK that would leave the separator to AWK would be `awk '{$5=$4;$4=$3;$3=0}1'` I would prefer this for just that reason

Comment: For me `awk` does not preserve the actual `FS` and uses instead space (default). So to keep the file tab-separated I had to do `awk '$2 = $2 "\t0"' file`

Comment: If the file is tab separated, tell `awk` about it: `awk -F'\t' '$2 = $2 FS "0"' file` works as expected.

Comment: Thank you, I went for awk '$2 = $2 FS "0"'

Comment: The sed solution is good, and could be simplified (which also keeps the spacing as in the samples given): `sed 's/./0/21'` will replace the 21st character with a `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{$2=$2" "0; print }' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> echo "Affx-11749850 1 555296 CC"|awk '{$2=$2" "0;print}'
Affx-11749850 1 0 555296 CC
```